# Integrate curio with pillow library

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-imaging-library, curio

**curio** library provides async `aopen()` function, while **pillow** has it's own `Image.open`. I want to create thumbnail and suggest **pillow** is smart enough not to load all image into memory while creating thumbnail. It looks like this:

```
self.image = Image.open(path)
self.image.thumbnail((300, 300))
```

How this can be integrated with the **curio** library?
For me it looks like I have two options:

- Call `aopen()`, load data into memory, then create `Image` object from in-memory data and call `Image.thumbnail()`
- Make `Image.open()` async wrapping with `async_thread` decorator, but it requires fire all thread machinery.

Is there some better approach for integrating curio and pillow for this task?

Comment: Are you sure that opening the file is slow enough to worry about it? In what context is this?

Comment: @syntonym It's not only about opening one or several files. It's about how to integrate async library with **pillow** for efficient use.  Also it might be required to generate thumbnails for all (or major part of) files beforehand, for example in inserted SD-card from photo camera.

Comment: Opening a single file should be so fast that using async IO for that is not needed. Opening many files should be IO bound so that using async IO shouldn't give you a speed boost. If you are webserver than of course the time you open files syncronously you can't answer requests, which would be one reason to use async IO. I think the "correct way" depends on your context. `aopen()` is implemented as `run_in_thread`: https://github.com/dabeaz/curio/blob/master/curio/file.py#L84

Comment: @syntonym 1. I want to know how to integrate these two libraries anyway, because I use both. 2. When I call `Image.open()` I get `Image` object, from which I can create thumbnail (I'm pretty sure it doesn't load whole 20Mb picture into memory for that). 3. Implementation of `aopen()` might be changed in the future as soon as general AIO will be added into linux kernel.